# Block off buttons until specific button is pressed

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm still learning Visual Basic so I'm not entirely sure what I should be searching for however I've just been given a task to make a cash machine simulation, nothing that I can submit for coursework it's just for fun. However I'm trying to find out how to block out any buttons until a button prior to it is pressed. For example, I have a button that simulates entering your credit card and then a progress bar. However, I want the buttons 1 - 9 to be blocked until the progress bar has finished. My current code is:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    barProgress.Increment(5)
    If barProgress.Value = 100 Then
        MsgBox("Please insert your pin into our secure system.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsertCard_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsertCard.Click
    Timer1.Start()

    If btnInsertCard.Text = "Insert Your Card" Then
        btnInsertCard.Text = "Please wait.."

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "2"
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "3"
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "4"
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "5"
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "6"
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "7"
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "8"
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "9"
End Sub

Private Sub btn0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "0"
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtNumber.Clear()
End Sub
```

End Class

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use the `.Enabled` property of the buttons.  `btnX.Enabled = (barProgress.Value = 100)`  might work in place of an If block

Comment: Does this work in Visual Basic?

Comment: If it doesn't, then let me know :) just a thought, if I could make it work then happy days but if not then it's not an issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're wanting to use is the `.Enabled` property.

In the Form1_Load I'm setting the `.Enabled` property for all of the buttons to `False`.

Once the `barProgress.Value = 100` I stop the timer and enable the first button.

Then in the click event for each button I set the `.Enabled` property for the next button to `True`.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim buttonArray = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0}

    For Each button In buttonArray
        button.Enabled = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "1"
    btn2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    barProgress.Increment(5)
    If barProgress.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        btn1.Enabled = True
        MsgBox("Please insert your pin into our secure system.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsertCard_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsertCard.Click
    Timer1.Start()

    If btnInsertCard.Text = "Insert Your Card" Then
        btnInsertCard.Text = "Please wait.."

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "2"
    btn3.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "3"
    btn4.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "4"
    btn5.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "5"
    btn6.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "6"
    btn7.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "7"
    btn8.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "8"
    btn9.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "9"
    btn0.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btn0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
    txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text & "0"
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'txtNumber.Clear()
    txtNumber.Text = Nothing
End Sub

End Class
```

*Edit - Sorry I read your question wrong somehow. Corrected my answer.